# How do you construct a grep & command to match a number of patterns depending on how many are provided at runtime?

Tags: shell-script, grep

I have exported some *MS Word* documents to plain text and use this function to parse the contents of the `.txt` files in the current directory:

```
mo1 () {
for i in *.txt; do
    echo "File: $i"
    grep -n -HC 1 "$@" "$i"
done
}
```

If I had more than one pattern to look for, I could do `mo1 | grep pattern2`. But what if I want to do something the result of which would be like `grep -E 'pattern1.*pattern2[.*...]...'` depending on how many patterns are supplied to the function at runtime i.e. `mo1 pattern1 pattern2 [...]` etc.? I can see the `@` array could provide the number of items and I could construct over a loop a variable (finalpattern='$1.*$2.*$3') that would end up being the expression used for `grep`. But I can't think of how to abstract that bit where you craft the expression in the function? Or is there a better/simpler way to do something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can leverage the `printf` builtin.

```
mo1 () {
  for file in *.txt; do
    grep -n -C1 "$(printf "%s.*" "$@")" "$file"
  done
}
```

This simple version inserts `.*` after the last element. It doesn't matter for this specific use case, but in other cases (e.g. `grep -o`) you may need to strip off the extra `.*` at the end.

```
mo1 () {
  pattern=$(printf "%s.*" "$@")
  pattern=${pattern%??}
  for file in *.txt; do
    grep -n -C1 "$pattern" "$file"
  done
}
```

In bash, you can put the `printf` output directly in a variable, which is slightly faster than using a command substitution (but this is unlikely to ever matter, even on Cygwin where subshells are slow).

```
mo1 () {
  printf -v pattern "%s.*" "$@"
  pattern=${pattern%??}
  for file in *.txt; do
    grep -n -C1 "$pattern" "$file"
  done
}
```

If you wanted to insert a single character between the positional parameters, you could set `IFS` to that character and use `"$@"`. But that doesn't work if the separator is more than one character. In ksh and bash, if there's a character that doesn't appear in the pattern, you can use that for joining and then perform a replacement. For example, here, it wouldn't make sense for patterns to contain newlines, so:

```
mo1 () {
  typeset IFS=$'\n'
  typeset pattern="$*"
  pattern=${pattern//$'\n'/.*}
  for file in *.txt; do
    grep -n -C1 "$pattern" "$file"
  done
}
```

In zsh, of course, there's a direct way.

```
mo1 () {
  for file in *.txt; do
    grep -n -C1 ${(j:.*:)@} $file
  done
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all the insight!! I think with the first one, I get some interaction because of C1, as if the output lines are context lines of the lines that contained the patterns, whereas they don't themselves contain it - at least I had that with the 3 terms I used for trying out the solutions. Otherwise this works flawlessly and will be very useful, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the `--file` option to grep:

```
-f FILE, --file=FILE
    Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains
    zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.  (-f is specified by POSIX.)
```

Comment: Thanks! The idea is interesting but when you create such a pattern file it's really doing OR i.e. it will find lines with either patterns from that pattern file...